# Grab object out of mongodb and place it in the $scope

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, ng-view

I am trying to grab the identifier of a product out of the url (eg. `/product/<productId>`), grab the Product object out of mongodb and make that object accessible in the `$scope` of my application. Grabbing the productId out of the url works fine with `$routeParams`, but I am having a hard time *getting the object out of the mongodb and into the scope.*

**My guess is that I need to add code in the `products-controller.js` on the server side, but how can I call the productId from the $scope on the server side?**

I know what the query should look like (eg. `db.products.find({_id : ObjectId("5422c8b2d4cc50e99f007f73")})`)

**server.js**
    `app.get('/api/products', productsController.list);`

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('productApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/productsoverview.html',
            controller: 'productsController'
        })
        .when('/product/:productId', {
            templateUrl: '/views/productFocus.html',
            controller: 'productFocusController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
}]);

app.controller('productsController', ['$scope', '$resource', 
    function($scope, $resource) {
        var Product = $resource('/api/products');

        $scope.products = [];

        Product.query(function (results) {
            $scope.products = results;
        });

}]);

app.controller('productFocusController', ['$routeParams', '$scope', '$resource', 
    function($routeParams, $scope, $resource) {
        if($routeParams.productId) {
            $scope.productId = $routeParams.productId

        }
}]);
```

**products-controller.js** (server)

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Product.find({}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I call the productId from the $scope on the server side?
>   pass the $scope.productId as a parameter, include it in the url like

your route on the server side could be something like

```
/api/products/:productId
```

then pass the parameter you get from the client url to your resource:

```
pp.controller('productsController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $resource,$routeParams) {
        var ProductEndpoint = $resource('/api/products/:productId',{productId:'@productId'});
        var product = new ProductEndPoint();
        product.productId = $routeParams.productId;
        $scope.products = [];
        Product.query(function (results) {
            $scope.products = results;
        });

}]);
```

**on the server side:**

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Product.find({_id:req.params.productId}, function (err, results) {
    res.json(results);
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an `illegal character` error on `var Product = $resource('/api/products/:productId',{productId:@productId});`

Comment: Check your code use jshint I can help you to find the answer but I'm not going to write your whole code... check the whole file sometimes your are getting the error and it's pointed to a different line of code

Comment: add single quotes to the parameter in the resource $resource('/api/products/:productId',{productId:'@productId'}); and try to read the angular js documentation